# Does Lk 8:3 rule out the theory that Mary Magdalene had had a life of promiscuity before she became a disciple of Jesus?

Tags: catholicism, gospel-of-luke, mary-magdalene

We read in Lk 8:1-3

> Soon afterwards he went on through cities and villages, proclaiming and bringing the good news of the kingdom of God. The twelve were with him,   as well as some women who had been cured of evil spirits and infirmities: Mary, called Magdalene, from whom seven demons had gone out,   and Joanna, the wife of Herod’s steward Chuza, and Susanna, and many others, **who provided for them out of their resources.**

One can understand the phrase `provided for ' in different ways. One possibility is that the ladies were preparing food for Jesus'team  after buying the raw material from their own savings. Another  is that the ladies were rich and contributed to the money bag that was kept by Judas Iscariot, and from which the team would draw money from time to time.

Now, the Gospels do not state much about the past life of Mary Magdalene, except for the mention of seven demons driven out of her. But, during a certain stage of the development of the Church,  a characteristic trait of promiscuous past life was attributed to her. But one seriously doubts if Jesus would ever have accepted money from Mary Magdalene , had she earned it with a life of promiscuity.

My question therefore is: According to Catholic scholars, does Lk 8:3 rule out the theory  that Mary Magdalene had had a life of promiscuity before she became a disciple of Jesus ?

Comment: 'Magdala' was a district of lower Galilee which historically was known as a centre of sorcery. Mary would have been what we call a 'medium'. There is no evidence in scripture (or elsewhere) for other suppositions.

Comment: Leaves me wondering how such a tradition got started.

Comment: Please google for  `Mary Magdalene  Wikipedia '. Thanks.